2020 Community Moderator Election Results
Chinese Language's first moderator election has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the three new moderators are:
  
They'll be joining the existing crew shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
Also, please join me in thanking your pro-tem moderators, Alenanno and Don Kirkby, who will be stepping down as moderators, as well as the previous pro-tems who helped this site through its beta phase (see here and here).
For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results here, or view a summary report online.  See also the 2020 election questionnaire.

Yay! Congrats to the elected moderators, you deserved it!

Thank you for everyone who voted for me. I would like to ask my fellow elected mods who have experience moderating this site for assistance. In other words, tell me what a mod does and doesn't do? I intend to keep my promise to be fair and reasonable, do as little as possibl.

Ohhh... third place was kind of close (!)

Congratulations to the winners, and special thanks to Alenanno, my fellow moderator for many years. Now, we can be ex-moderators together.

Congrats to everyone and a welcome to our two newest moderators.

 Took me by surprise that voting didn't quite match the voting on the answers from the questionnaire. Perhaps it wasn't as well read as I imagined. 

The easiest explanation is probably that the meta audience isn't the same as the main site audience. 100+ voters against max 6 upvotes to questionnaire answers. Moreover, SE sends you a notification to remind you to vote, but links to the questionnaire are much less prominent. Also answers are walls of text that people not fluent in English might not fully understand (or even finish reading, for that matter)
